# CodeIgniter returning different request format / content type html|json|xml etc

Tags: php, codeigniter, response, content-type

What is a simple way in CodeIgniter that I can return a specific content type for request URL extension?  For example I want to return json if the url is http://example.com/phone/digits/1.json, html if the URL ends in /1 or /1.html, and XML if the URL ends in /1.xml.  This will load a view in the format specified.  So in the above example (phone/digits/1.json) would return the json version of the digits method.  Here is what I've got so far that is NOT correctly working but gives an idea of what I'm going for.  It's currently generating a 404 if no arguments are passed (/phone/digits.json)...  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class Phone extends CI_Controller {
    public $layout = FALSE;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (preg_match('/\.(html|json)$/', $ci->uri->uri_string(), $matches))
        {
            $this->format = ('html' == $matches[1] || !isset($matches[1])) ? '' : '.json.php';  
        }
    }

    public function digits()
    {
      $this->load->view('phone/digits' . $this->format);
    }
```

Updated for clarity,

Comment: I understand if you dont send argument it gives 404 but what does `phone/digits/1.json` do exactly ?

Comment: It returns the json "view" file phone/digits.json.php.

Answer (score 1):

I didint understand your question well, asuming you want to simplify your url

its solution for this url : **http://domain.com/phone/digits.json** (xml or html also)
But with few modification , it can be useful  also with **http://domain.com/phone/digits/n.json** (n - id number)

in `config/routes.php`

```
$route['phone/digits.(json|html|xml|php)'] = 'Phone/digits/$1';
$route['phone/digits'] = 'Phone/digits';
```

Controller

```
class Phone extends CI_Controller {
public $layout = FALSE;

public function __construct()
{
  //hmm
}

public function digits($format = '')
{
   if($format == '') {
     //default view or something else
   }
   else {
      $this->load->view('phone/digits' . $format);
   }
}
```

Comment: safarov: I really appreciate the response but it wasn't quite what I was looking for.  I've updated the original post for clarity.

Comment: safarov: Problem is I'm trying to do this site wide so for every controller and every controller method.  I figured out if I override CI_Router I can fix the /phone/digits.json issue (it's looking for a "digits.json" method in the phone controller) but I can't for the life of me get CI to override the core router class even though I see online it's possible using a MY_Router class in the application/library folder.

Comment: Yes you can override Core library, controller and models as well. Create MY_controller inside Core folder and inside __controstuctor manage whatever you want, also you can do some forwarding at .htaccess

Comment: I've got a My_Router.php class (in application/libraries) that extends CI_Router and calls the parent classes constructor (parent:__construct()).  I'm missing something though cause it's not being called at all.

Comment: For the next person that comes allong My_Router.php needed to be in application/core.

Answer (score 0):

- Parse the url
- grab the extension
- use a switch condtional and set relevant output

-

```
switch( $extension ){
    case 'json':
          $this->output
               ->set_content_type('application/json')
               ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
    break;
    case 'xml':
          $this->output
               ->set_content_type('application/xml')
               ->set_output(file_get_contents(some_xml_file.xml));
    break;
    // etc etc
}
```